# Cold Dairy into lukewarm meat

Tags: halacha, meat-and-milk

If a cold dairy item (such as a liquid or solid) falls into lukewarm chicken soup, and The bowl had recently been hot, is the bowl treif?

Comment: Well, was the soup hot or not?

Comment: The soup had been hot, but by the time the dairy fell into the soup, it had turned lukewarm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the bowl is kosher.

As a general rule, things only become non-kosher through heat. According the the Rema ([YD 105:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9145&st=&pgnum=497)) the heat must be (a) from a "כלי ראשון"--a utensil that itself has been on the fire; AND (b) if the utensil is no longer on the fire, the non-kosher item must have fallen in immediately after the the utensil was taken off the fire so that the scalding heat is still present. The Aruch Hashulchan (ad loc.) notes that most poskim agree with the Rema. The Maharshal (see Shach ad. loc.) is more stringent. He holds that items can become non-kosher through heat the hand would recoil from, even if the utensil was never on the fire. Within this framework there are various potentially mitigating factors, but it is unnecessary to discuss them, because your case only involves lukewarm soup, and therefore does not meet the most basic criterion for rendering utensils non-kosher.

Comment: The ShA is machmir for Kli Sheni Lechatchila.

Comment: @DoubleAA This--and any typical case--is b'dieved. See Shach 105 s"k 5--in this context l'chatchila just means that you should not immerse a kosher item in a כלי שני of non-kosher, relying on washing off the kosher item, rather, you should keep them separate, but if you did, it's still kosher.

Comment: See R Akiva Eiger there that Keilim which can be Kashered is Lechatchila. I understand such is the psak of r Hershel Schachter. So yes the soup is kosher but the bowl might be treif.